# Unable to login into website after installing and setting up itweak_login

Tags: 7, users

After installing and tweaking [itweak_login](http://drupal.org/project/itweak_login) I got this error when I tried to re login into the site.

Any body have any ideas, how I can log in into the site. Sorry, unrecognized username or password.

**Notice Message:**

> Notice: Undefined variable: form_values in _itweak_login_user_login_final_validate() (line 266 of C:\Inetpub\websites\web.etfotvots.com\sites\all\modules\itweak_login\itweak_login.module).

Comment: you can disable the module from the database

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing that module's code, I have to agree with @Aboodred1 in his comment *you can disable the module from the database* for several reasons (which I'll address on the module's drupal.org page rather than this site because I don't think this site is the appropriate place to do so). This is **not** the preferred or recommended way to do things, but it seems like you might have no other choice if you've already installed it.

***Method 1***

1. **BACK UP YOUR DATABASE**
2. If you don't feel comfortable directly accessing your database, you should be able to log in to your web server and delete the `itweak_login` module directory (usually located inside `sites/all/modules`) and everything inside it. This should at least give you access back into your site. If that doesn't work, or if you do feel comfortable accessing/modifying your database directly, here's an elaboration on the aforementioned comment:

***Method 2***

1. **BACK UP YOUR DATABASE**
2. Log in to your web server and open the `settings.php` file for your Drupal installation (usually located at `sites/default/settings.php`)
3. Find the line that looks like this:

   ```
   $databases = array (
     'default' => 
     array (
       'default' => 
       array (
         'database' => 'mydrupal7database',
         'username' => 'mydatabaseusername',
         'password' => 'mydatabasepassword',
         'host' => 'localhost',
         'port' => '',
         'driver' => 'mysql',
         'prefix' => '',
       ),
     ),
   );
   ```
4. If the `prefix` line is empty (as it is in the example above), continue on to number 5

   1. If it's not empty, e.g. if it looks something like this: `'prefix' => 'drupal7_',` then replace the word `system` in step 7 with `drupal7_system` (in other words, add the prefix to the the word *system*)
5. Log in to your database if you're not already there
6. Select the database used for this particular Drupal installation (using the example above, you'd select the database called `mydrupal7database`)
7. Run the following SQL statement:

   ```
   UPDATE `system` SET `status` = 0 WHERE `name` = 'itweak_login';
   ```

Note: after you disable the module in the database, you should be able to access your site again. At this point, I'd highly recommend uninstalling it by visiting the module uninstall page (`admin/modules/uninstall`), and then after it has been uninstalled, remove it from your server altogether (using Method 1 above).

Hope that helps...

:)

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I change to another Web Browser, it works.
so here is a idea for this situation:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=766008

so it means other cookie make some issue
my enviroment:
Centos 6.2
Drupal 7.3.6
xampp 5.6.3-0
Browser:Google Chrome